# Github Actions - How can I create file in a new branch

Tags: github, github-pages, github-actions

I have a `dev` branch where I have Gatsby personal website. I also have a `main` branch accordingly which is used to publish my personal website.

I want to map GitHub pages to my custom domain. For this, I need a new file named `CNAME` in `main` with some content.

I found the following GitHub action in order to achieve file creation in the same branch.

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-file

I am looking for a similar GitHub action that can create a new file in a new branch.

Here's my current version of GitHub pages:

```
name: Publish saint1729 Personal Site

on:
  push:
    branches: [ dev ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: enriikke/gatsby-gh-pages-action@v2.1.1
        with:
          access-token: ${{ secrets.portfolio }}
          deploy-branch: main
          gatsby-args: --prefix-paths
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `uses: actions/checkout@v2` you have a checkout of your code. You can create a branch by calling `git branch the-of-the-branch`. And with `git push` you can push it to the origin repository.

Comment: Do I need to use my token for authentication? Do you have a sample example for this?

Comment: A token is available in every action: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow I don’t have an example available.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question of an action that would allow you to push a specific file to a specific branch, this might help:

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/add-commit

I chose this because it's evolved (v7) and has had many contributors.